# How to send logs from elk siem to arcsight?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elk, arcsight

I need to gather data from Elk to ArcSight. The official documentation only describes how to get data from ArcSight to ELK. How can I gather logs from ELK to ArcSight?

Is it possible to implement this with the logstash? How can I do it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.